# PHP SimpleXML Object Property Exists as Array but Turns into Object when Accessed Directly

Tags: php, arrays, object, simplexml

I'm experiencing a strange issue when attempting to parse a response from Authorize.Net's CIM API. PHP uses the API's response to create a SimpleXML object. A property of the object reports as being an array (and is, as it contains 2 unique indexes,) however when the property is accessed directly, print_r(), gettype(), and is_array() all report/treat it as an object, not as an array.

The following PHP code:

```
print_r($parsedresponse);
print_r($parsedresponse->profile);
print_r($parsedresponse->profile->paymentProfiles);
```

Generates the following output:
    SimpleXMLElement Object

```
(

    [messages] => SimpleXMLElement Object

        (

            [resultCode] => Ok

            [message] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                (

                    [code] => I00001

                    [text] => Successful.

                )

        )
    [profile] => SimpleXMLElement Object

        (

            [merchantCustomerId] => 1

            [description] => Customer Profile for Store Code MC Created 11/20/13

            [email] => email@email.com

            [customerProfileId] => 11111111

            [paymentProfiles] => Array

                (

                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                        (

                            [customerType] => individual

                            [billTo] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                                (

                                    [firstName] => Test

                                    [lastName] => Test

                                    [company] => Company Name

                                    [address] => 1234 Test St

                                    [city] => Testlyvania
                                    [state] => OH

                                    [zip] => 44720

                                    [country] => United States

                                    [phoneNumber] => 123-456-7890

                                    [faxNumber] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                                        (

                                        )

                                )

                            [customerPaymentProfileId] => 22222222

                            [payment] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                                (

                                    [creditCard] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                                        (

                                            [cardNumber] => XXXX1111

                                            [expirationDate] => XXXX

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                        (

                            [customerType] => individual

                            [billTo] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                                (

                                    [firstName] => Test

                                    [lastName] => Test

                                    [company] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [address] => 1234 Test St

                                    [city] => Testlyvania

                                    [state] => OH

                                    [zip] => 44720

                                    [country] => United States

                                    [phoneNumber] => 1234567890

                                    [faxNumber] => 123-456-7890
                                )

                            [customerPaymentProfileId] => 33333333

                            [payment] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                                (

                                    [creditCard] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                                        (

                                            [cardNumber] => XXXX0002

                                            [expirationDate] => XXXX

                                        )

                                )


                        )

                )

            [shipToList] => Array
                (

                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                        (

                            [firstName] => Test

                            [lastName] => Test

                            [company] => Company Name

                            [address] => 1234 Test St

                            [city] => Testlyvania

                            [state] => OH

                            [zip] => 44720

                            [country] => United States

                            [phoneNumber] => 123-456-7890

                            [faxNumber] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                                (

                                )

                            [customerAddressId] => 44444444
                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (

                            [firstName] => Test

                            [lastName] => Test

                            [company] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                                (

                                )

                            [address] => 1234 Test St

                            [city] => Testlyvania

                            [state] => OH

                            [zip] => 44720

                            [country] => United States

                            [phoneNumber] => 1234567890

                            [faxNumber] => 123-456-7890

                            [customerAddressId] => 55555555
                        )

                )

        )

)


SimpleXMLElement Object

(

    [merchantCustomerId] => 1

    [description] => Customer Profile for Store Code MC Created 11/20/13

    [email] => email@email.com

    [customerProfileId] => 11111111

    [paymentProfiles] => Array

        (

            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                (

                    [customerType] => individual

                    [billTo] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                        (

                            [firstName] => Test

                            [lastName] => Test

                            [company] => Company Name

                            [address] => 1234 Test St

                            [city] => Testlyvania

                            [state] => OH

                            [zip] => 44720

                            [country] => United States

                            [phoneNumber] => 123-456-7890

                            [faxNumber] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                                (

                                )

                        )

                    [customerPaymentProfileId] => 22222222

                    [payment] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                        (

                            [creditCard] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                                (

                                    [cardNumber] => XXXX1111

                                    [expirationDate] => XXXX
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                (

                    [customerType] => individual

                    [billTo] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                        (

                            [firstName] => Test

                            [lastName] => Test

                            [company] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                                (

                                )

                            [address] => 1234 Test St

                            [city] => Testlyvania

                            [state] => OH

                            [zip] => 44720

                            [country] => United States

                            [phoneNumber] => 1234567890

                            [faxNumber] => 123-456-7890

                        )

                    [customerPaymentProfileId] => 33333333

                    [payment] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                        (

                            [creditCard] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                                (

                                    [cardNumber] => XXXX0002

                                    [expirationDate] => XXXX

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [shipToList] => Array

        (

            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                (

                    [firstName] => Test

                    [lastName] => Test

                    [company] => Company Name

                    [address] => 1234 Test St

                    [city] => Testlyvania

                    [state] => OH

                    [zip] => 44720

                    [country] => United States

                    [phoneNumber] => 123-456-7890

                    [faxNumber] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                        (

                        )

                    [customerAddressId] => 44444444
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                (

                    [firstName] => Test

                    [lastName] => Test

                    [company] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                        (

                        )

                    [address] => 1234 Test St

                    [city] => Testlyvania

                    [state] => OH

                    [zip] => 44720

                    [country] => United States

                    [phoneNumber] => 1234567890

                    [faxNumber] => 123-456-7890

                    [customerAddressId] => 55555555
                )

        )

)


SimpleXMLElement Object

(

    [customerType] => individual

    [billTo] => SimpleXMLElement Object

        (

            [firstName] => Test

            [lastName] => Test

            [company] => Company Name

            [address] => 1234 Test St

            [city] => Testlyvania

            [state] => OH

            [zip] => 44720

            [country] => United States

            [phoneNumber] => 123-456-7890

            [faxNumber] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                (

                )

        )

    [customerPaymentProfileId] => 22222222

    [payment] => SimpleXMLElement Object

        (

            [creditCard] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                (

                    [cardNumber] => XXXX1111

                    [expirationDate] => XXXX

                )

        )

)
```

As you can see, once the "paymentProfiles" property is accessed directly, it goes from being of type Array to type Object. However if I were to try to access it's second index directly, that works just fine.

The PHP code:

```
print_r($parsedresponse->profile->paymentProfiles[1])
```

Produces the following output:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object

(

    [customerType] => individual

    [billTo] => SimpleXMLElement Object

        (

            [firstName] => Test

            [lastName] => Test

            [company] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                (

                )

            [address] => 1234 Test St

            [city] => Testlyvania

            [state] => OH

            [zip] => 44720

            [country] => United States

            [phoneNumber] => 1234567890

            [faxNumber] => 123-456-7890

        )

    [customerPaymentProfileId] => 33333333

    [payment] => SimpleXMLElement Object

        (

            [creditCard] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                (

                    [cardNumber] => XXXX0002

                    [expirationDate] => XXXX

                )


        )

)
```

Why when access directly does $parsedresponse->profile->paymentProfiles behave like an object rather than an array as expected?

Comment: `print_r` and `var_dump` are practically useless for `SimpleXMLElement`. Almost every child node and attribute itself will be a `SimpleXMLElement` even if it looks like an array on the surface

Answer (score 0):

This other answer seems to have most of the information you need.  It helped me: [Why does SimpleXML change my array to the array's first element when I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796797/why-does-simplexml-change-my-array-to-the-arrays-first-element-when-i-use-it?rq=1).  The foreach loop worked well for me, though a standard for loop works as well.

So you should be able to do the following, even though $parsedresponse->profile in not an array according to print_r.  It should also work if $parsedresponse->profile is an array.

```
print_r($parsedresponse);
foreach($profile as $prof){
    print_r($prof);
    foreach($prof->paymentProfiles as $pProf){
        print_r($pProf);
    }
}
```