# Simplexml only shows first array elements even with children() method

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, simplexml

I'm using PHP 5.6.

I'm consuming an amazon API and getting back some products form a product search.

I have got the raw xml string back and loaded it in to simplexml with

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
```

Now if I do

```
print_r($xml->response->Items);
```

I get (condensed):

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[Request] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [IsValid] => True
    )

[TotalResults] => 8914365
[TotalPages] => 891437

[Item] => Array
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [ASIN] => B00QJDO0QC
                [ParentASIN] => B00U879AII
            )
        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [ASIN] => B01HDUE8HE
                [ParentASIN] => 000000000
            )
        [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [ASIN] => B72HEUD9HE
                [ParentASIN] => 000000000
            )
        )
    )
```

So I want to isolate the 'Items' array so I can process the returned items. So I obviously do:

```
$items = $xml->response->Items->Item;
```

But now if I do

```
print_r($items);
```

I don't get the three elements, I just get a print out of the FIRST $items element like so:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [ASIN] => B00QJDO0QC
    [ParentASIN] => B00U879AII
)
```

I read here: [Why does SimpleXML change my array to the array's first element when I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796797/why-does-simplexml-change-my-array-to-the-arrays-first-element-when-i-use-it) that you need to use the ->children() method. So I tried:

```
print_r($items->children());
```

With still the same output.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Rule of thumb: don't trust `print_r` with SimpleXML. Just follow the structure you expect to be there, using `foreach` etc, and it will (usually) Just Work [tm].